# Android Emulator gives blue screen of death

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device, vpc

No matter which type of android virtual device I create from the Android SDK and AVD Manager, whenever I start it, my entire laptop just shuts down after getting the blue screen of death. I see this error in the Event system Log ("Driver VPCAppSv.sys has been blocked from loading.") but not sure if it's related to it or not.

Anyone have any ideas?  I've installed again 3 times with no luck.

Comment: Please provide the error shown in the BSOD. You might want to disable automatic restarts on BSOD to be able to read the text and the error shown.

Comment: Here's what it says on the Blue screen that's readable:

csacentr.sys - Address 89CF50E5 base at......

So it looks like there's an issue with the Cisco Security Agent?  But not sure what that has to do with the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably conflict with some device. You should notice file that cause conflict (name of file that you see on blue screen). Next, check what this file do (for example of what driver is) and try to switch off this app/ hardware. I had the same problem. On blue screen I saw the file embda64.sys. I checked that this file is a part of driver of my PVR-TV USB device (external TV Tuner). After turning this device off in device manager, emulator started to work well.