# Windows 10 blue screen of death when starting AVD Android 10.0 API 29

Tags: android, windows-10, android-virtual-device

When I create new AVD Android 10.0 API 29 and run it then Windows 10 shows blue screen of death. AVD Android 9.0 and 8.1 working fine. 
Laptop:
Dell G3, CPU i5-8300H 4.0 GHz, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD

[image]

Comment: This should be targeted at Google issue tracker. First, go through [known bugs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=emulator%20bsod), if you don't find anything [report new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192727&template=843117).

Comment: Could this hardware be a problem?

Comment: Have you tried here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550421/android-emulator-gives-blue-screen-of-death?rq=1

Comment: update [HAXM driver](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.2)

Comment: Like @magicandre1981 I'd update the Intel HAXM driver and ensure that in android studio all SDK updates are installed. If no luck there like Eugen Pechanec said, looking and/or raising an issue with the Google issue tracker is probably the best place

Comment: I've updated HAXM driver. Windows 10 didn't show BSOD, but AVD shows only black screen

Comment: change GPU settings for the virtual phone

Comment: GPU changed; didn't work

Comment: Thank you guys, I have fixed it by using x86_64 image. Before I was using x86 image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `Intel HAXM` is updated.

**File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK | SDK Tools Tab**

[image]